# How to capitalize first line with CSS? ::first-line pseudo-element not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, line, pseudo-element, capitalize

Right now I've got a paragraph and I'd like to capitalize the entire first line. I've set the first paragraph to an ID "firstp" and tried:

```css
#firstp::first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I've tried it with `text-transform: capitalize` but that doesn't work either. It's strange because I've managed to change the first letter (changed font size) using `#firstp:first-letter`.

Comment: The paragraph content is static or dynamic?

Comment: try adding a semicolon (`;`) after `uppercase` to properly end the property.

Comment: it seem to only happen on WebKit (FireFox renders fine).

Comment: @knittl, the last semicolon in a stylesheet declaration block is optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`text-transform` on `:first-line` is really buggy right now, see the reference here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-transform

You can use this jquery plugin called **linify** https://github.com/octopi/Linify to select the first line and then apply the property of `text-transform: uppercase`

Regards,

Comment: WebKit browsers seem to have bug here, first reported in 2006 if not earlier (http://beckleyworks.com/2006/03/30/css-bug-discovered/), and still not fixed. So some JavaScript approach is needed if you wish to have cross-browser uppercasing for first line (which isn’t such a great typographic device even when it works).

Comment: Seems to still be an issue with webkit browsers today in 2015. Wow. Webkit not up to CSS3 standards yet...

Answer (score 2):

I think Chrome has a problem with ":first-line".  Try removing that and using james31rock's syntax on this page, except in his example the CSS should be "#firstp{..." to reflect the ID in his HTML rather than ".makeupper".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

It looks better in my opinion and is supported in all major browsers.

More info

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps

Comment: As most fonts have no small caps version, you would make browsers use reduced-size uppercase letters, which are typographically awful.

Comment: But if you happen to be using a font with a 'small caps' version, this is a very good solutions. +1

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you must use the following Pseudo-element within the correct syntax. Example:

HTML PORTION:

```
<selection id="Welcome">
<p>Some text</p>
</section>
```

CSS SHEET:

```
#Welcome p:first-of-type:first-line {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I hope this helps. Sorry for the late entry. I guess, better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

There might be another way ...

What if you have two spans with text inside paragraph, one of the spans would have position set to upper left corner of the paragraph, so the two spans would overlap. Now set height of the upper span to about `line-height` of your text and `overflow` to hidden so only first line of the span would be visible. Set `text-transform` to uppercase on the upper span and vou la you have first line in uppercase.

**Downside of this solution** is, uppercase text is wider so there might be missing words on next line. You can fix this by using [**fixed-width**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font or try to set `letter-spacing` on both spans so width of uppercase and lowercase texts would be same.

[Here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kw8mw6kp/2), though it's not ideal sometimes when you change the window size, **it might be sufficient**.

Answer (score -1):

It doesnt seem to work either way, in Chrome. In I.e. text-transform works. I do not have firefox to test with.

http://jsfiddle.net/vJSeq/4/ - using text-decoration

http://jsfiddle.net/vJSeq/3/ - using text-transform

You can see that the selector is right because it is highlighted.

My suggestion would be to use something to seperate the text you want highlighted, by creating a span tag inside of the paragraph and assign it a class

```
<p id="firstp">to stop the degradation of the planet's natural environment and to build a future in <span class="makeupper">which humans live in harmony with nature, by; conserving</span> the world's biological diversity, ensuring that the use of renewable natural resources is sustainable, and promoting the reduction of pollution and wasteful consumption.</p>
​
```

and the css

```
.makeupper
{
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vJSeq/5/

Comment: Yes, after testing it does work in Internet Explorer. Still would like to find a way to get it to work in Chrome as that is the main browser used here.

Comment: Im not sure thats possible. You can use javascirpt to eval the first line and wrap a span tag around it, then apply the css to the span tag/