# p.class:first-line does not work

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the :first-line pseudo selector but it seems not to be working, and I cannot figure out why. I've tried using ::first-line as well but to no avail. (Note, this has nothing to do with border radius).

```css
p.intro:first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="intro">Instead of attempting to cover the full range of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> selectors, I think it makes sense to begin with a subset of the most widely supported. The <a href="http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html">compatibility charts compiled by Peter-Paul Koch</a> provide
  detailed support information.</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it shouldn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/9wrubwc2/

Comment: @Anonymous In fact there's an example in the MDN using `text-transform: uppercase`...

Comment: @DenysSéguret You are correct, my bad. I guess I read the "The color property, all background-related properties" part and assumed that text-transform was not included.

Comment: oddly, the inspector shows that the actual HTML is uppercase and the :first-line is not found in the css section

Comment: I've tried this code *without* the :first-line and in that instance it works. By the way, my code comes directly from a textbook I'm working from (Beginning CSS3 by David Powers, Chapter 2)

Comment: Replacing that with background-color seems to work. Seems a quirk or bug, because as far as I can see from the docs `text-transform` should apply as well.

Comment: @DenysSéguret There we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808992/how-to-capitalize-first-line-with-css

Comment: @Anonymous I saw that, too.  From what it looks like, this has been an open issue for quite some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only see this issue in Chrome.  Apparently there's a bug that has not been fixed yet: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129669

There is a workaround proposed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808992/how-to-capitalize-first-line-with-css) which says you can use **https://github.com/octopi/Linify** to get the effect using a jquery plugin.  Essentially, use **linify** to select the first line and then apply the property of `text-transform: uppercase` to the first line.

Comment: I've also tried it in Opera, and Safari (on a Mac). Doesn't work. It does work in Firefox. Webkit bug?

Comment: @Steven All of them use the same web engine (webkit, blink) therefore have same bug. Try Firefox or IE instead

Comment: @steven I ran the snippet on the latest version of Firefox (Win 7) and it works as expected.

Comment: @Steven it worked in Firefox for me.  I think WebKit is the issue here.

Comment: the MDN article does add that in the working draft options are restricted and this might be removed